# How to refactor the method of `IsAuthenticated` to provide a better api

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a `IsAuthenticated` method which has a complex argument type (I copied it from play2's zentasks example):

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[(Action[AnyContent], AnyContent)] =
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { userId =>
    Action { implicit request =>
      val email = request.session("user.email")
      f(email)(request)
    }
  }
```

In order to use it, my action is:

```
def delete(id:String) = IsAuthenticated { email => request =>
   ...
}
```

You can see I have to declare `email` event if I don't need to use it. I can use `_` instead:

```
def delete(id:String) = IsAuthenticated { _ => _ =>
   ...
}
```

But `_ => _ =>` is still boring.

How to refactor the method to let it's usage simpler? e.g. If I don't need `email` and `request`, I can:

```
def delete(id:String) = IsAuthenticated {
   ...
}
```

If I just need `request`, I can:

```
def delete(id:String) = IsAuthenticated { request =>
   ...
}
```

If I need `email`, then I declare them all:

```
def delete(id:String) = IsAuthenticated { email => request =>
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overload the `IsAuthenticated` to provide the different flavours you need. For example:

```scala
def IsAuthenticated(result: => Result) = IsAuthenticated { _ => _ => result }
```

You can then use it as follows:

```scala
def delete(id:String) = IsAuthenticated {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, compilation error: `double definition: method IsAuthenticated:(f: => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[(play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent], play.api.mvc.AnyContent)] and method IsAuthenticated:(f: => models.SessionUser => play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] => play.api.mvc.Result)play.api.mvc.Action[(play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent], play.api.mvc.AnyContent)] at line 18 have same type after erasure: (f: Function0)play.api.mvc.Action `

Comment: Change the initial `IsAuthenticated` to `def IsAuthenticated(f: String => Request[AnyContent] => Result)` (use a by-value parameter).